# Result of function that includes pre- and post-increment differs

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

I had to understand some code which mixes pre- and post-increments in functions. There was one thing that confused me.

So I tried to test some smaller function. But I could not explain following behaviour:

```
int i = 1;
i = i++ * ++i * 2;
System.out.println("i = " + i);
int x = 1;
x = ++x * x++ * 2;
System.out.println("x = " + x);
```

The expected output was:

```
 i = 8
 x = 8
```

But actually is:

```
 i = 6
 x = 8
```

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `i++ * ++i * 2` --> **1** * 3 * 2 --> 6
- `++x * x++ * 2` --> 2 * **2** * 2 --> 8

Important values in **bold**.

The difference between the prefix and postfix increment when returning values in Java can be better summarized by Oracle themselves (my **bold** again for highlighting purposes):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will both end in result being incremented by one. **The only difference is that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original value**. If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it doesn't really matter which version you choose. But if you use this operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may make a significant difference.

Source [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

In your specific case, as the postfix evaluates to the original value and the order of operations is left to right for same arithmetic operator - here, only multiplier applies - your operations are translated as above.

Answer (score 1):

Post-increment increases the value of `i` but does not immediately assign the new value of `i`.

Pre-increment increases the value of `i` and is immediately assigned the new value.

Thus, in your example for y, after `i++`,

`i` has become `2` but it is still holding on to the previous value of `1`.

When `++i` occurs, `i` with the value of 2 will be increased by `1` and simultaneously, assigned the new value of `3`. Therefore, `1 * 3 * 2` gives us the value `6` for `y`.

The same goes for `x`,

when `++x` occurs, `x` is immediately assigned the new value of `2`.

However, when `x++` occurs, x is increased by `1` **but** is still assigned the previous value of `2`. Therefore, `2 * 2 * 2` gives us `8`.